# ASP MVC Use authentication cookie across domain websites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, cross-domain, forms-authentication

I have multiple websites that use the same cookie for authentication. They are suppose to log in on the portal website and can then visit multiple websites.

**for example:**

portal.ilvo (only website with login form) 
site1.ilvo
site2.ilvo
siteX.ilvo

I have set the domain in my cookie for .ilvo but It seems I can't login at all.

**Web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms 
      name="iwa.authentication" timeout="10080"slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" 
      cookieless="UseCookies"
      enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain=".ilvo" />
</authentication>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by publishing each website on a different port so they all have the same domain.

Comment: See "full detail" section of this [answer](/a/36315292/1178314) if you wish more information on cookie transmission rules regarding top domains.